# Intellisense - Iterate list using different key other than Up/Down Arrows

Tags: intellisense

I was wondering if its possible to customize the behavior of IntelliSense in VS 2012. I also have Resharper installed if that can do it. My desire is to minimize the amount of movement of my hands from the core keys. Typically when IntelliSense comes up I start typing and it narrows the list down to say 3-4 items. Then I need to move my right hand to the Down Arrow Key. I was wondering if I could use the Space key to cycle through the short list of 3-4 items and then hit Enter or ; to select the value I wanted. I can always keep typing the item I want  but sometimes that will take 6+ keystrokes since the names are similar. Anyway just wondering as I would think that would be an improvement in speed.